# Redundant Functions?

Tags: functions, terminology

Consider the function $f:\mathcal P(\Bbb N)\to\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ such that $f(A)=\{a:a\in A,a\text{ prime}\}$. This has the property of not having any effect upon being iterated, i.e. $f(A)=f(f(A))=\cdots$. I was wondering what this property would be called and why/whether it is important to anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such functions are called **idempotent** and are characterised by $f(x)=f(f(x))$. As [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) says, this notion comes up in abstract algebra.

Comment: Great answer! What would it be called when $f^n(x) = f^{n+1}(x)$ for some finite $n$ (rather than just $f^1(x) = f^2(x)$)?

Comment: @AustinWeaver It's still idempotent, just of a higher order.